# How to schedule pods restart

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to restart pods automatically based on the time?

For example, I would like to restart the pods of my cluster every morning at 8.00 AM.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Use a cronjob, but not to run your pods, but to schedule a Kubernetes API command that will restart the deployment everyday (`kubectl rollout restart`). That way if something goes wrong, the old pods will not be down or removed.

Rollouts create new ReplicaSets, and wait for them to be up, before killing off old pods, and rerouting the traffic. Service will continue uninterrupted.

You have to setup RBAC, so that the Kubernetes client running from inside the cluster has permissions to do needed calls to the Kubernetes API.

```
---
# Service account the client will use to reset the deployment,
# by default the pods running inside the cluster can do no such things.
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: deployment-restart
  namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
---
# allow getting status and patching only the one deployment you want
# to restart
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: deployment-restart
  namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps", "extensions"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    resourceNames: ["<YOUR DEPLOYMENT NAME>"]
    verbs: ["get", "patch", "list", "watch"] # "list" and "watch" are only needed
                                             # if you want to use `rollout status`
---
# bind the role to the service account
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: deployment-restart
  namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: deployment-restart
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: deployment-restart
    namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
```

And the cronjob specification itself:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: deployment-restart
  namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: '0 8 * * *' # cron spec of time, here, 8 o'clock
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 2 # this has very low chance of failing, as all this does
                      # is prompt kubernetes to schedule new replica set for
                      # the deployment
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 600 # timeout, makes most sense with 
                                 # "waiting for rollout" variant specified below
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: deployment-restart # name of the service
                                                 # account configured above
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: kubectl
              image: bitnami/kubectl # probably any kubectl image will do,
                                     # optionaly specify version, but this
                                     # should not be necessary, as long the
                                     # version of kubectl is new enough to
                                     # have `rollout restart`
              command:
                - 'kubectl'
                - 'rollout'
                - 'restart'
                - 'deployment/<YOUR DEPLOYMENT NAME>'
```

Optionally, if you want the cronjob to wait for the deployment to roll out, change the cronjob command to:

```
command:
 - bash
 - -c
 - >-
   kubectl rollout restart deployment/<YOUR DEPLOYMENT NAME> &&
   kubectl rollout status deployment/<YOUR DEPLOYMENT NAME>
```

Comment: While this doesn't technically answer the question asked, this is (IMO) by far the best option for periodic restarts of a cluster's pods!

Comment: This answer saved our live and helped us to overcome a huge incident and money loss while investigating and fixing the root cause. Thank YOU!

Comment: From https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs. **Caution**: All CronJob schedule: times are based on the timezone of the kube-controller-manager. If your control plane runs the kube-controller-manager in Pods or bare containers, the timezone set for the kube-controller-manager container determines the timezone that the cron job controller uses.

Comment: @OhJeez     Can I restart just the oldest pod (not all) if I have 30 pods running for a deployment using this?

Comment: A counterpoint: don't host resources with the ability to self-modify a k8s cluster, isolate those tasks in a separate cronjob tool, external to the cluster. Ideally, this tool should be the one offered by the service provider managing your cluster -- e.g. https://cloud.google.com/scheduler for GKE, or in the case of AWS, a second ECS cluster for running highly sensitive jobs in other ECS clusters

Comment: Notice however that changes to `ServiceAccount` require elevated priviledges (cluster admin), while `livenessProbe` approach can be used by ordinary devs...

Comment: Hey @OhJeez, 
I have the same use case want to restart two k8s deployments which run in separate clusters, What I am not able to understand is where do I need to add the RBAC YAML ? Inside the service i want to restart or the k8s job which will trigger restarts?

Comment: Update: in CronJob change `batch/v1beta1` to `batch/v1` to make it work

Comment: Hi, I just have a question, why does it work with the service account created by us and not with the default service account. Is it the permission issue given to service account and if yes can we change the permissions? Is it recommended? The solution worked for me, thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 41):

Another quick and dirty option for a pod that has a restart policy of **Always** (which cron jobs are not supposed to handle - see [creating a cron job spec pod template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#writing-a-job-spec)) is a livenessProbe that simply tests the time and restarts the pod on a specified schedule
**ex. After startup, wait an hour, then check hour every minute, if hour is 3(AM) fail probe and restart, otherwise pass**

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - exit $(test $(date +%H) -eq 3 && echo 1 || echo 0)
  failureThreshold: 1
  initialDelaySeconds: 3600
  periodSeconds: 60
```

Time granularity is up to how you return the date and test **;)**

Of course this does not work if you are already utilizing the liveness probe as an *actual* liveness probe **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Maybe should add the minutes in the command, otherwise it will always auto restart at 3:00~3:59. `- exit $(test $(date +%H%M) -eq 0300 && echo 1 || echo 0)`

Comment: Surely this approach would cause it to continually restart during the specified period, like a whole minute. Using precision to the second makes it potentially possible to miss the check all together. Maybe checking uptime if the update is greater than 24 hours would be simpler and more appropriate?

Comment: This approach does avoid restart storms by waiting an hour after startup to begin the probe again (initialDelaySeconds)  so anywhere between 3:00 and 3:01 it fails, and then once it restarts it waits an hour to start checking time again (with startup time for a fairly large vert.x app ~ 25 seconds, first probes start between 4:01 and 4:02)

Comment: @Philluminati your uptime suggestion is a great one for a regimented 24 hour restart, but if you were trying to schedule the restart for a certain time you would need to time your initial startup to match

Comment: The above liveness command cannot be written on one line this way. You can use `- bash`, `- -c`, and `- exit $(test $(date +%H) -eq 3 && echo 1 || echo 0)` on three separate lines though.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari you are correct, since the test is run in the pod's Docker container, the date / test / exit commands are entirely dependent on the container's shell

Comment: @RyanLowe, while applied this code, It will automatically restart each time after "initialeDelayseconds" occurred. it is not validate - exit $(test $(date +%H%M) -eq 0300 && echo 1 || echo 0) condition. can you please help me to make it correct?

Comment: This approach has some downtime. After liveness probe fails and before the container is restarted, pod cannot accept traffic. If all containers happen to restart at the same time, there will be service interruption.

Comment: @OhJeez that is absolutely true, the livenessProbe will cause downtime as all pods from that deployment will restart simultaneously, the cronjob you describe below should be the accepted answer for production :)

Comment: Thank you. I needed a temporary hack because on production my app is having an issue that needs restart each 24 hours. I fixed the code long ago but company policy for deployment is veeeery slow. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Use `sh` not `bash` to be certain it is available everywhere (e.g. in Alpine):`- sh` | `- '-c'`|`- exit $(test $(date +%H) -eq 3 && echo 1 || echo 0)`

Comment: Is there a reason why we wouldn't simplify the bash command to just `exit 1` and then extend the `initialDelaySeconds` to be the frequency we want to restart on? Does it fire more often than expected?

Comment: the simpliest way would be to check every hour rather than every minute.. else it will restart 60 times when its 3am as its doing it every minute. if its checking every 3600 seconds, then it should restart only once per day.

Answer (score 14):

I borrowed idea from @**Ryan Lowe** but modified it a bit. It will restart pod older than 24 hours

```
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
             - bin/sh
            - -c
            - "end=$(date -u +%s);start=$(stat -c %Z /proc/1 | awk '{print int($1)}'); test $(($end-$start)) -lt 86400"
```

Comment: `/proc/1` is not a reliable source of information. The timestamp can be very different from reality. I would use `ps -p 1 -o etimes --no-headers` when available and when the process ID is known ("1" in my case).

Answer (score 6):

There's a specific resource for that: [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

Here an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: your-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/20 8-19 * * 1-5"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: your-periodic-batch-job
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-image
            image: your-image
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

change `spec.concurrencyPolicy` to `Replace` if you want to replace the old pod when starting a new pod. Using `Forbid`, the new pod creation will be skip if the old pod is still running.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this works. Does it deploy a new pod and thus Kubernetes automatically remove one of the old pods?

Comment: the implication is that the command in `your-image` does something to trigger the pod to restart.

Comment: @StuartHarland Are you sure? My interpretation is that `your-image` is your service, and it runs until the next time the cron job fires, when `Replace` stops it and starts a new instance. Of course it would work the way you suggest too, but it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 4):

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - "exit 1"
  failureThreshold: 1
  periodSeconds: 86400
```

where 86400 is a desired period in seconds (1 restart per day in this example)

Answer (score 2):

According to [cronjob-in-kubernetes-to-restart-delete-the-pod-in-a-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762491/cronjob-in-kubernetes-to-restart-delete-the-pod-in-a-deployment)
you could create a `kind: CronJob` with a `jobTemplate` having `containers`. So your CronJob will start those containers with a `activeDeadlineSeconds` of one day (until restart). According to you example, it will be then `schedule: 0 8 * * ?` for 8:00AM

Answer (score 1):

We were able to do this by modifying the manifest (passing a random param every 3 hours) file of deployment from a CRON job:

We specifically used Spinnaker for triggering deployments:

We created a CRON job in Spinnaker like below:

Configuration step looks like:
[image]

The Patch Manifest looks like: (K8S restarts PODS when YAML changes, to counter that check bottom of post)
[image]

As there can be a case where all pods can restart at a same time, causing downtime, we have a policy for Rolling Restart where maxUnavailablePods is 0%

```
 spec:
  # replicas: 1
     strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
       rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 50%
          maxUnavailable: 0%
```

This spawns new pods and then terminates old ones.