# Kubernetes shcedule restart pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have `Deployment` that runs 5 pods.

I want to restart all pods each 5min.

Currently I'm doing it with python scritpt that is running `kubectl get po` and checks AGE, if the AGE bigger than 5 min it deletes the pod.

Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: What is the use case for the restarts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule pods restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422300/how-to-schedule-pods-restart)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a liveness check to achieve this, but why would you do it? Deployment is for LongRunning Tasks.

A liveness check will reschedule a pod if its not true (gives a other exit code than 0)

For more Info here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/